# How to interpret xerror of rpart (method="class") when losses are assigned

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

I would like to prune my rpart classification tree and to do so I need to understand how the cross-validated classification error, i.e., xerror, are calculated **when losses are assigned**.
For simplicity, let consider two class classification problem (say A and B). Then in my understanding, error is

# of misclassification to class A x Loss of misclassification to class A +
# of misclassification to class B x Loss of misclassification to class B

So I expect xerror is this error in cross-validated data. 
However, I am seeing very strange result in xerror. Here is a simple example

```
N <- 1000
p <- 50
ilogit <- function(eta){
  1/(1+exp(-eta))
}
dat <- matrix(rnorm(N*p,mean=-3),nrow=N)
coeff <- (1:ncol(dat))*0.001
(x <-rbinom(N,size=1,prob=ilogit(dat%*%coeff))) 
mydat <- data.frame(dat,x=x)
>table(x)
 0   1 
978  22
```

Notice that class 1 is rare event so only 22 observations in class 1.
Now I fit rpart with loss 10 times larger for the misclassification of class 1 into class 0 than the missclassification of class 0 into class 1.

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(x~.,data=mydat,method="class",
             parm=list(loss=matrix(c(0,1,
                                    10,0),2,2,byrow=TRUE)))
printcp(fit)
```

The output is:

```
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = x ~ ., data = mydat, method = "class", parms = list(loss = matrix(c(0, 
    1, 10, 0), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
 [1] X1  X10 X13 X14 X17 X19 X35 X37 X39 X8  X9 

Root node error: 220/1000 = 0.22

n= 1000 

        CP nsplit rel error xerror     xstd
1 0.061364      0   1.00000 0.1000 0.021084
2 0.050000      9   0.36364 2.4136 0.316196
3 0.018182     11   0.26364 2.7727 0.338565
4 0.010000     13   0.22727 3.4091 0.373655
```

Strangely initial xerror is extremely small and it is 0.1000 (I see this is 1/loss of class 0), then xerror increases to 2.41, 2.77 and so on. Somehow xerror at the initial node is much much better than rel error!! If I change the loss of class 0 to be even larger then even more strange things happen:

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(x~.,data=mydat,method="class",
             parm=list(loss=matrix(c(0,1,
                                    100000,0),2,2,byrow=TRUE)))
printcp(fit)
```

The output is:

```
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = x ~ ., data = mydat, method = "class", parms = list(loss = matrix(c(0, 
    1, 100000, 0), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
 [1] X15 X17 X18 X2  X20 X27 X28 X30 X32 X35 X36 X38 X39 X41 X49 X50 X7  X8 

Root node error: 978/1000 = 0.978

n= 1000 

         CP nsplit rel error xerror    xstd
1  0.182004      0   1.00000 100000  474.29
2  0.116564      1   0.81800  76278 1407.50
3  0.100204      2   0.70143  65031 1555.75
4  0.067485      3   0.60123  58180 1601.24
5  0.057260      4   0.53374  47853 1613.39
6  0.049080      5   0.47648  42945 1595.88
7  0.040900      6   0.42740  37219 1555.75
8  0.033742      7   0.38650  32106 1500.68
9  0.028630      8   0.35276  30368 1477.46
10 0.025562      9   0.32413  27301 1430.44
11 0.021472     10   0.29857  24949 1388.73
12 0.019427     12   0.25562  21779 1323.85
13 0.017382     13   0.23620  20859 1302.96
14 0.014315     14   0.21881  19530 1271.02
15 0.013292     16   0.19018  18916 1255.53
16 0.011247     17   0.17689  16667 1194.31
17 0.010000     20   0.14315  12168 1046.94
```

So this time, xerror is by far worse than relative error. This time, initial xerror seems to be the loss of class 0 (NOT reciprocal of it unlike the last time). Also, xerror is constantly getting better when tree grows.

Could you tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes after a lot of time but I arrived to a (partial) solution of this bizzare result after I tackled a similar problem.

1. If we take a closer look on the first variation of the problem (*the one with a loss of 10*) we observe that the root node error is calculated as following:

   - [("Loss of class 1") * ("# number of actual ones")]/("size of the dataset)

   Conceptually this means that if we classify all data points on the majority 
   class we will have a **weighted error rate** as described above.

Increasing though the loss of class 1 will eventually make the fraction bigger than one! In that case the tree structure starts its hypothesis of classifying everything on the class one (simply because it is optimal in term of cost)!!

**Important**: In the case that the loss values of both classes lead to root node error greater than one, the one with the less cost is picked as the tree's choice of initial classification.

---

2. In all the cases the initial cross-validation mean error (*xerror*) is calculated by the following formula:

   - (loss value of class A)/ (loss value of class B),

   where A is each time the class which is determined to be optimal as a universal classifier in the root node. (e.g. if we had the loss of class 0 to be 2 and class 1's to be 3, the xerror value on the root node would be 0.66667)

**Note:** On the examples of the question @ThePrincess assumption is correct beacause the loss of class zero is unity

---

3. As far as it concerns the reason for the performance of xerror values I tend to believe that on the first example the tree suffers from severe overfitting leading the tree with only the root node to be optimal, while on the latter case we obviously get a better solution as we drive deep because we compare it to an initial solution where all our data are basically misclasified on the beggining (we had only 22 out of 1000 ones and yet we start by classifying everything as one).

p.s This has been my first answer ever on the platform. I hope it helps! (Advice for improving the structure of my answer are welcome!)